# Adjective meaning "of the genitals"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there a word that means "of the genitals" or something similar? Example usage would be something like: "the genitalic tissue." Thanks!

Comment: This is what dictionaries are for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*[Genital](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/genital)* is the adjectival form:

> adjective
>
> 1. Relating to the human or animal reproductive organs:
>
> <sub>ODO</sub>

From *[Women's Sexual Function and Dysfunction: Study, Diagnosis and Treatment](https://books.google.com/books?id=3J7TnwpbZQwC&pg=PA746&dq=%22genital%20tissue%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=XBqGVdy0K62xsASZt7TQDA&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22genital%20tissue%22&f=false)*, by Irwin Goldstein, et al:

> The vascular nature of genital tissue lends itself to many parallel
>   comparisons from the already established field of cardiovascular
>   biology.

The noun usage, generally the plural *genitals*, developed before the plural *[genitalia](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/genitalia)* was introduced as a clinical term in the 19th century:

> late 14c., "pertaining to (sexual) reproduction," in *membres genytal*
>   "the genitals,"
>   from Latin *genitalis* "pertaining to generation or
>   birth; fruitful" (also a by-name of the goddess Diana),
>   from *genitus*,
>   past participle of *gignere* "to beget" (see *genus*).
>   Hence the English
>   word came to mean "pertaining to the organs of generation."
>   As a noun
>   meaning "sex organ" from mid-15c. (plural *genitals* is from late 14c.).
>   <sub>etymonline</sub>

Notice the [relative frequency](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=genital_NOUN%2C%20genital_ADJ%2Cgenitals%2Cgenitalia&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgenital_NOUN%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgenital_ADJ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgenitals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgenitalia%3B%2Cc0) of the terms *genital*, *genitals*, *genitalia* and *genital* (noun):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I think you'll find that "[genital](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/genital)" is already an adjective.

> Relating to the human or animal reproductive organs: the genital area